# Should we favor [social-media] tag over individual social media names, like Twitter or Facebook?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [social-media](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media), [facebook](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook), and [twitter](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter) tags. Many questions about the named site contain the more generic social-media tag as well. Should we burn named tags or the social-media tag? Is there a reason to have both?

Comment: Can you quantify how many posts are in these categories and point to a few examples ecplaining why you see an issue with them. (I'd suspect if it's generically about 'social'-media then naming one might be a kind of product-placement?)

Comment: Can we imagine someone wanting to search for questions about Twitter (the platform), and not for Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

**When I find more time, I'll update with what I can find for other social media sites and make a recommendation for usage**

First impressions are that it's appropriate to have all three tags, but there's a good deal of misuse

---

## **Simple Analysis**

### For questions tagged [social-media](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media)

**Basic Metrics**

- 44 questions total with the tag
- 2 questions are negative score, 1 zero score.

  - The zero score question is marked as duplicate, the others are still open.
- 4 questions closed, 0 on-hold, 2 marked as duplicate, none of these also tagged Facebook or Twitter

**Misuse**

- 16 questions seem to be not about social media or even a specific social media site.

  - 12 of these seem to make the connection with social media only in that the claim was found on social media
  - 2 are "twitter prediction" type questions, and are not actually about social media or twitter, but one think they are because the predictions were made via twitter.
  - 2 contain the tag for opaque reasons.

**Also tagged [twitter](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter)**

- 1 question also tagged [twitter](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter)

  - This 1 question is about exclusively Twitter and Donald Trump's use of it
  - 4 questions not tagged twitter seem to be exclusively about Twitter and not social media in general

**Also tagged [facebook](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)**

- 3 questions also tagged [facebook](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)

  - All three are exclusively about Facebook, but the case that social media in general is relevant can be made for 2 of them
  - 4 questions not tagged facebook seem to be exclusively about Facebook and not social media in general

### For Questions tagged [facebook](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)

**Basic Metrics**

- 12 questions total with the tag
- 2 questions are negative score, both still open.
- 0 questions closed, 0 on-hold, 0 marked as duplicate.

**Misuse**

- All 12 questions seem to be about Facebook

  - 1 is specifically asking if a facebook page is legitimately belonging to the company it claims to belong to. It has a negative score, but it not closed.

**Also tagged [twitter](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter)**

- 0 questions also tagged [twitter](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter)

**Also tagged [social-media](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media)**

- 3 questions also tagged [social-media](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media)

  - All three are exclusively about Facebook, but the case that social media in general is relevant can be made for 2 of them

### For Questions tagged [twitter](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter)

**Basic Metrics**

- 6 questions total with the tag
- 0 questions are negative or zero score
- 2 questions closed, 0 on-hold, 0 marked as duplicate, neither of these also tagged Facebook or social-media

**Misuse**

- 4 questions seem more about people tweeting rather than about twitter the company and website

**Also tagged [social-media](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media)**

- 1 question also tagged [social-media](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media)

  - This 1 question is about exclusively Twitter and Donald Trump's use of it

**Also tagged [facebook](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)**

- 0 questions also tagged [facebook](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)